# Solve right linear set equations

Tags: automata, computational-mathematics, formal-grammar

Trying to solve this set of equations. I'm feeling like I'm making it so complicated.
Of course + is union. Am I on the right track?

A = 0B + 1D
  B = 0C + 1A
  C = 0A + 1B + λ 
  D = OD + 1C + λ

A = 0B + 1(0*1C + 0*) = 0B + 10*1C + 10*
  B = 0C + 1A
  C = 0A + 1B + λ 
  D = OD + 1C + λ = 0*1C + 0*

A = 0(0C + 1A) + 10*1C + 10* = 00C + 01A + 10*1C + 10*  = 01A + (00 + 10*1)C + 10* = (01)*((00 + 10*1)C + 10*)
  B = 0C + 1A
  C = 0A + 1B + λ

A = (01)*((00 + 10*1)C + 10*)
  B = 0C + 1((01)*((00 + 10*1)C + 10*))
  C = 0A + 1B + λ

A = (01)*((00 + 10*1)C + 10*)
  B = 0C + 1((01)*((00 + 10*1)C + 10*))
  C = 0((01)*((00 + 10*1)C + 10*)) + 1(0C + 1((01)*((00  + 10*1)C + 10*))) + λ

A = (01)*((00 + 10*1)C + 10*)
  C = 0((01)*((00 + 10*1)C + 10*)) + 1(0C + 1((01)*((00  + 10*1)C + 10*))) + λ 
  C = 0(01)*(00 + 10*1)C + 0(01)*10*  + 10C + 11((01)*((00 + 10*1)C + 10*)) + λ
  C = 0(01)*(00  + 10*1)C + 0(01)*10* + 10C + 11(01)*(00 + 10*1)C + 11(01)*10* + λ
C = (0(01)*(00  + 10*1) + 10 + 11(01)*(00  + 10*1))*(0(01)*10* + 11(01)*10*)

A = (01)*((00 + 10*1)((0(01)*(00  + 10*1) + 10 + 11(01)*(00 + 10*1))*(0(01)*10* + 11(01)*10*)) + 10*)
  C = 0((01)*((00 + 10*1)C + 10*)) + 1(0C + 1((01)*((00  + 10*1)C + 10*))) + λ 
  C = 0(01)*(00 + 10*1)C + 0(01)*10*  + 10C + 11((01)*((00 + 10*1)C + 10*)) + λ
  C = 0(01)*(00  + 10*1)C + 0(01)*10* + 10C + 11(01)*(00 + 10*1)C + 11(01)*10* + λ
  C = (0(01)*(00  + 10*1) + 10 + 11(01)*(00  + 10*1))*((0(01)*10* + 11(01)*10*) + λ)

Final Answer 
A = (01)*(((00 + 10*1)((0(01)*(00 + 10*1) + 10 + 11(01)*(00 + 10*1))*((0(01)*10* + 11(01)*10*) + λ))) + 10*)

**edit**: fixed it.

Comment: So the task is to convert a regular grammar into a regular expression for the same language, right? (It looks like Markdown has eaten some of the stars in your final answer, by the way).

Comment: @HenningMakholm yes. this is the task. I fixed my answer. Look right? this is the way?

Comment: It may or may not be _right_ but for sure it's _ugly_. Are you required to use a particular systematic procedure, or is it anything-goes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A -> 0B + 1D
B -> 0C + 1A
C -> 0A + 1B + λ
D -> 0D + 1C + λ
```

we can eliminate B

```
A -> 0(0C + 1A) + 1D
C -> 0A + 1(0C + 1A) + λ
D -> 0D + 1C + λ
```

and distribute

```
A -> 00C + 01A + 1D
C -> 0A + 10C + 11A + λ
D -> 0D + 1C + λ
```

and collect

```
A -> 00C + 01A + 1D
C -> (0+11)A + 10C + λ
D -> 0D + 1C + λ
```

now look at D, we can use the kleene star to eliminate the recursion

```
A -> 00C + 01A + 1D
C -> (0+11)A + 10C + λ
D -> (0)*1C + (0)*λ
```

and then eliminate it

```
A -> 00C + 01A + 1(0)*1C + 1(0)*λ
C -> (0+11)A + 10C + λ
```

and collect

```
A -> 01A + (00+1(0)*1)C + 1(0)*λ
C -> (0+11)A + 10C + λ
```

we can also make C non-recursive in the same way

```
A -> 01A + (00+1(0)*1)C + 1(0)*λ
C -> (10)*(0+11)A + (10)*λ
```

and then eliminate it

```
A -> 01A + (00+1(0)*1)((10)*(0+11)A + (10)*λ) + 1(0)*λ
```

and distribute

```
A -> 01A + (00+1(0)*1)(10)*(0+11)A + (00+1(0)*1)(10)*λ + 1(0)*λ
```

and collect

```
A -> (01+(00+1(0)*1)(10)*(0+11))A + (00+1(0)*1)(10)*λ + 1(0)*λ
```

and make it non-recursive

```
A -> (01+(00+1(0)*1)(10)*(0+11))*((00+1(0)*1)(10)*λ + 1(0)*λ)
```

now this is a regular expression.

Comment: When "solving a system of equations" is it sufficient to give the solution to only one of the variables?

Comment: @HendrikJan, you can solve the rest if you want

Comment: @Spenrers, thanks. I understand. Assuming this is homework, I was wondering what the professor would expect as answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by drawing the automaton to get an intuitive handle on what's going on:

[image: diagram of finite automaton]

It looks like the key states are A and C. We can write down an easy set of expressions for getting from one of A,C to another one without meeting A or C along the way:

```
{A2A} = 01
{A2C} = 10*1|00
{C2A} = 0|11
{C2C} = 10
```

Now, something that gets us from A to A once (with no intermediate As, but possibly Cs):

```
{AA} = {A2A} | {A2C}{C2C}*{C2A} = 01|(10*1|00)(10)*(0|11)
```

An finally an expression for the entire automaton:

```
L = {AA}* ( {A2D} | {A2C}{C2C}* ) =
   ( 01|(10*1|00)(10)*(0|11) )* ( 10* | (10*1|00)(10)* )
```